# Using gulp correctly showing the js file in the console

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, browserify, console.log

I am using gulp, browserify and exorcist (and more) - I bundle all of my javascript files into one so when I console log something in app.js in the console it shows thats its on line 14 in main.js(which is accurate).

In development I want to show in the console the correct file and line its coming from. How can I do this?

Comment: I think that only applies to the debugger function - which I have working, not the console log.

Comment: You think wrong; you want sourcemaps.

Comment: Yes had sourcemaps - I had to fix something in my gulp file to map it.